# Intersect two polygons with geopandas.sjoin not working

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, intersection, spatial-join

I have two GeoDataFrames which I am trying to intersect using the following:

```
gpd.sjoin(left_df=geomap_ilot_geomatic, right_df=all_titres_updated,  how="left", predicate="intersects")
```

This function worked fine for many cities but for this particular example it is not working.

Here are the dataframes:

```
geomap_ilot_geomatic (`crs='EPSG:4326'`)
```

[image]

```
all_titres_updated (`crs='EPSG:4326'`)
```

[image]

Both dataframes have the same coordinate system (`crs='EPSG:4326'`). When I project them on QGIS I get an overlap (see picture below- color green is `geomap_ilot_geomatic` and color red is `all_titres_updated`) which implies that there is a possibility of intersecting.

I am confused as to why the function `gpd.sjoin` is not working for this particular example.

[image]

Comment: do you mean `sjoin` or `join` - please add the crs of each layer as text not an image

Comment: I mean`sjoin` . I added `crs='EPSG:4326'` in the question. The CRS is adjusted when I read the shape file.

Comment: Can you share the geometries as text, or it is not possible to test